# SQL condition in join statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to use a conditional statement in join (SQL Server)

```
select * from A inner join B
on A.id = B.id
```

if `B.id is null or B.id = ''` it should be `A.id2 = B.id2` instead of `A.id = B.id`

Is it correct if i do something like this:

```
   select * from A inner join B on  
   (B.id is not null and B.id <> '' and A.id = B.id) or 
   ((B.id is null or B.id = '') and A.id2 = B.id2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not the best way to solve this problem, but could be useful, also is very simple:

```
SELECT * FROM a INNER JOIN b
 ON a.id = b.id
UNION 
SELECT * FROM a INNER JOIN b
 ON a.id2 = b.id2
 WHERE b.id IS NULL OR b.id = ''
```

Comment: I don't think this will give the result that OP wants. I believe a negation of the `b.id IS NULL OR b.id = ''` condition should be added to the first part.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from A inner join B
on (A.id = B.id) OR ((B.id is null or B.id = '') && (A.id2 = B.id2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CASE` statement

```
SELECT *
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
ON  CASE
        WHEN B.id IS NULL OR B.id = '' THEN A.id2
        ELSE A.id
    END
    =
    CASE
        WHEN B.id IS NULL OR B.id = '' THEN B.id2
        ELSE B.id
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
  DECLARE @b varchar(50)=(SELECT id FROM b)
DECLARE @a varchar(50)=(SELECT id FROM a)
if ((@b in (null , '')) and (@a in (null , '')))

BEGIN

select * from A inner join B
on
A.name = B.name 

END
else

BEGIN

select * from A inner join B
on A.id = B.id 

END
```