# Case in SQL join statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to use a conditional statement in join:

```
select * from A inner join B
on A.id = B.id
```

if `B.id is null or B.id = '' or A.id is null or A.id = ''` it should be `A.name = B.name`, instead of `A.id = B.id`

I have to use a conditional statement in join:

```
select * from A inner join B
on A.id = B.id
```

if `B.id is null or B.id = ''` it should be `A.id2 = B.id2` instead of `A.id = B.id`.

Is it correct if I do something like this:

```
select *
from A inner join B on  
   (B.id is not null and B.id <> '' and A.id is not null and A.id <> '' and A.id = B.id) or 
   ((B.id is null or B.id = '' or A.id is null or A.id = '') and A.name = B.name)
```

Comment: Did you try it? Did it give you the results you wanted?  I don't see any `CASE` in your SQL....

Comment: Duplicate of [SQL condition in join statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29813333/sql-condition-in-join-statement) please don't ask the same question two times in a row

Answer (score 0):

I think you will want something like this:

```
 select * from A
 inner join Bid on  
    (Bid.id is not null and Bid.id <> '' and A.id is not null and A.id <> '' and A.id = Bid.id)
 inner join Bname on 
   ((Bname.id is null or Bname.id = '' or A.id is null or A.id = '') and A.name = Bname.name)
```

that is to join on the `B` table twice, one join for when `id` is not null and the second join when `id` is null and you join on the `name` column instead.  This works effectively like a case statement because the two joins to the `B` table are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 select * from A inner join B
 on (A.id = B.id) or 
 (A.name = B.name and (B.id is null or B.id = '' or A.id is null or A.id = ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
  DECLARE @b varchar(50)=(SELECT id FROM b)
DECLARE @a varchar(50)=(SELECT id FROM a)
if ((@b in (null , '')) and (@a in (null , '')))

BEGIN

select * from A inner join B
on
A.name = B.name 

END
else

BEGIN

select * from A inner join B
on A.id = B.id 

END
```